# Stof Doctrine extension:Tree lvl doesn't update

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, stofdoctrineextensions

I'm asking this question here because I'm having no answer on github.

I'm using the nested tree annotation and supposedly when one save a $food object like that:

```
$food->setParent($vegetables);
```

the update of the parent, lvl and root is done correctly.
However since I update to Symfony 2.5 the update of the lvl isn't working anymore, it stays at 0, making this tree extension useless.

I can't even force it (if I manually change the lvl before persisting, after the flush lvl is back to 0)...

Does anyone has the same issue ?

Comment: What happens if you refresh the entity after flushing?

Comment: I don't know what about the author, but in my case update actually works.

Comment: I've had comments on github from other people having the same issue. I for one simply wrote a tree function and forgot about this extension. @Jean what do you mean by refreshing the entity ?

Comment: I can tell instead of @Jean - when I persist and flush entity and right after that I set lvl or parent of given entity than everything is ok. When I create new entity - then it doesn't work.

Comment: @Eagle1 I mean calling `$em->refresh($entity);`, it reloads the entity from the DB

Comment: doesn't help as I said the entity is persisted with the wrong values inside the DB...

Comment: which version of stof/doctrine-extenstion you use?

Comment: I'm using 2.4.13 (latest stable) and still having this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing more of your code it's hard to tell exactly what the issue is.

However I'd recommend trying something like:

```
$foodRepository = $entityManager->getRepository('AppBundle:Food');
$foodRepository->persistAsFirstChildOf($vegetables, $food);
$entityManager->flush();
```

Comment: With persistAsLastChildOf($vegetables, $food) method it doesn't update it. With the first it updates it as expected.